# Is it posible to programmatically check if the selenium Remote Webdriver Server is running or not

Tags: c#, selenium, remotewebdriver

Hi is it possible to check if the Remote webdriver server is running or not using C#. Pinging the server did not help , Can you tell what type of call should be done and what will be the feedback that we can expect from the server

Comment: have you googled the code for it?

Comment: Yes , i was not able to find any , Since i cant ping what can i do to check if the selenium server is up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really define what you mean by 'running'.

You *can* get the general status of the server by chucking a JSON request at it.

You see the server will implement the Wire Protocol, so it means that it will, or at least *should*, respond to the following list of REST url's:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol

Specifically:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/status

and possibly

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#GET_/sessions

The `status` supposedly, will:

`The server should respond with a general "HTTP 200 OK" response if it is alive and accepting commands`

If this is what you mean by 'running', that it is alive and kicking and willing to accept commands, then you will need to send off a request to `/status` and check for the response you get back.

Comment: Thank u it solved my issue all i had to do i make a get request to the following url Http://127.0.0.0.1/wd/hub/status